# Platform sh site setup in localhost gets Cookie error

Tags: errors, cookies, debug

I have setup up a WordPress project from Platform sh in my local host. I get get the project by using the platform get [id] command. I Imported the database in my localhost and configured the wp-config.php file and then I have run the platform build command and the build is successful. I have also run platform mount: download to download cache and uploads folder inside wp-content folder. But when I open the site in my localhost it's not showing the pre-signon page and it's not opening /wp-admin/ page. When I open the site it's directly redirecting to the/wp-login.php/ page. And when I try to log in using my username and password it's showing below cookie error:

Error: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

I have renamed /themes/ folder and /plugins/ folder to /themes-old/ and /plugins-old/ and tried to log in but it's still showing the same error. Here is the screenshot attached for the error:

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted platform.sh support? And confirmed it with a standard normal WordPress install? Your screenshot has styling that is not standard WordPress and non-standard functionality. There's not enough information to debug the problem in your question

Comment: Actually, I imported the database of the live site into my local host and tried to run the project. Then I tried to log in with the same admin credentials as in my live site but it's showing the above cookie error. I don't think there is any mistake about platform sh. I have also set up another similar website from platform sh in my local host and it is working fine.
I searched for the above error in my code files and this message is present in my WordPress default wp-login.php file. And then I checked the wp-login.php file of fresh WordPress installed and this message is also present there.

Comment: } elseif ( isset( $_POST['testcookie'] ) && empty( $_COOKIE[ TEST_COOKIE ] ) ) {
    // If cookies are disabled, the user can't log in even with a valid username and password.
    $user = new WP_Error(
     'test_cookie',
     sprintf(
      /* translators: %s: Browser cookie documentation URL. */
      __( '<strong>Error:</strong> Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must <a href="%s">enable cookies</a> to use WordPress.' ),
      __( 'https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/cookies/#enable-cookies-in-your-browser' )
     )
    );
   }

Comment: This code is present in the wp-login.php file for all the WordPress sites by default.

Comment: then it's extremely likely the cause is that your URLs mismatch between local and production and you have forgotten to perform a search replace, and that is why you're getting this issue, because WP cannot set a cookie for the production domain. If it did work then it's likely WP would have redirected you instead to the production site

Comment: No, I am trying to run the project in my localhost by creating a virtual host. I have created virtual host and when I open the site its directly redirecting to the wp-login page not to the production site. Below is the link where I am redirecting when I tried to open mybcom.local.
http://mybcom.local/wp-login.php

Comment: Actually, there is a pre-sign-on page too on my site. This page must open first while opening the site. And one more thing, when I try to open /wp-admin it's also redirecting to /wp-login

Comment: exactly your using a `.local` domain for your local site, the URL is not the same as your production site, you can't just import a live websites SQL dump into a local site that has a different URL, you need to perform a search replace to change your production URL to the local URL, wether that's a raw IP, or a vhost with a nice local domain and an entry in your hosts file, or a Bonjour zeroconf domain such as `.local`. ***Are you sure you've raised this with platform.sh support?***

Comment: No, I haven't raised this issue with platform support. Actually, I am working on a client's project I have access to the platform sh via terminal only. I don't have platform sh login access to ask the question to support.

Comment: After importing the database to the localhost, I changed the site URL and home URL in the wp_options table.
I have done the same with another project mymcom and which is working fine in my localhost using vitualhost.

Comment: _only_ the options table and nowhere else? I would expect at a minimum for that to cause broken assets etc

Comment: Do I need to search and replace all the links of the live site in my local database?
I am a little newbie here so. Anyway, thanks for replying Tom.

Comment: yes, especially if it's a multisite. WP CLI can do it for you and handle serialised PHP if your URLs have different lengths, else a naive SQL statement will corrupt those values. You should also double check `wp-config.php` for `COOKIE_DOMAIN` and other config values

Comment: Actually, I have also tried putting the below code in the wp-config.php file.

define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', false);
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');

And I have also tried the below code in the functions.php file.

setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
if ( SITECOOKIEPATH != COOKIEPATH ) setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the code below in the `settings.php` file to boycott cookies solved my issue.

```php
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your wp-config.php file, you need to make sure `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` are set for your local environment.  How you do that will depend on what you are using for your local development. I would suggest using [DDEV](https://ddev.com/) or [Lando](https://lando.dev/) as Platform.sh has integrations for both. [DDEV](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/providers/platform/), [Lando](https://docs.lando.dev/platformsh/). Combine them with the wp-config.php file from one of [Platform.sh's WordPress templates](https://github.com/platformsh-templates?q=wordpress&type=all&language=&sort=), and it should just work without any additional changes on your part.